# Once connected to RRAS VPN in Windows 7 can't access local domain resources

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, pptp

I'm connected to our remote data center via RRAS VPN which is running as a Domain Controller.  The client I'm connecting with is on our local domain.

Once I'm connected to the remote domain using my credentials all local resources become unavailable.  I'm able to contact them and ping them, however if I use Windows Authentication it fails to authenticate.

Is there anyway I can be able to be VPN'd into the remote domain and authenticate with the local and remote domains?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

open %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk using notepad

Search for

UseRasCredentials=1

Replace with

UseRasCredentials=0

Save it, from then on local windows auth will work as well. You will have to redo this everytime you add a new VPN connection however

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use your local credentials by explicitly specifying the domain you are using:

```
mylocaldomain\username
```

That way the machine you are connecting to can figure out which domain controller to talk to.

Comment: Well, what about something like SSMS where you can't specify a username?  It just accepts your windows credentials and it looks like they're being replaced by the VPN Domain.